# ORACLE LISTAGG the values

Tags: oracle, listagg

I have 2 tables TABLE1 and TABLE2  and joining these two tables, is TABLE3 which is my expected result. Have attached all the details in the screenshot. It will be really helpful if anyone can provide solutions to this. Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rdHA.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are going to aggregate like that, what will you do with the results of LISTAGG? These days data is transmitted in structured formats, for example JSON. Creating a JSON array of objects with keys Role and Rank is almost as easy as LISTAGG, and the result is in a format that is much more widely used than the one you show in your desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much ..yes you are right...But here the req is fetching from a view and using it in a soap service with xml structure...which will be consumed by the legacy downstream system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data in lines #1 - 8; query that does the job begins at line #10.

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (categoryid, categoryname, categorydesc) as
  3    (select 1, 'C1', 'Category 1' from dual),
  4  table2 (identifier, categoryid, role, rank) as
  5    (select 9001, 1, 'ZT01',  1 from dual union all
  6     select 9002, 1, 'ZT01',  1 from dual union all
  7     select 9002, 1, 'ZT04', -1 from dual
  8    )
  9  --
 10  select a.categoryid,
 11         a.categoryname,
 12         a.categorydesc,
 13         b.identifier,
 14         listagg(b.role ||':'|| b.rank, ', ') within group (order by b.role) rolerank
 15  from table1 a join table2 b on a.categoryid = b.categoryid
 16  group by a.categoryid,
 17           a.categoryname,
 18           a.categorydesc,
 19           b.identifier;

CATEGORYID CA CATEGORYDE IDENTIFIER ROLERANK
---------- -- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 C1 Category 1       9001 ZT01:1
         1 C1 Category 1       9002 ZT01:1, ZT04:-1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. this worked...I think this will work in volume of 200 millions or more....But if you have any other performance improvement suggestion please let me know.. thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it'll work. For 200 million rows or more, it'll take time to finish. The only "limit" is length of the final string aggregated in LISTAGG - it can't contain more than 4000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

--Untested

```
SELECT CATEGORYID, CategoryName, CategoryDesc ,  
LISTAGG(rolerank, ",") WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CATEGORYID,identifier )
(
SELECT CATEGORYID, CategoryName, CategoryDesc, identifier, role || ':' || rank as rolerank 
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOINT TABLE2 T2 ON T1.CATEGORYID = T2.CATEGORYID
) GROUP BY CATEGORYID, CategoryName, CategoryDesc
```